# Send the Date Formatted data from String via Unirest POST getting - Invalid input

Tags: java, http, server, response, unirest

I send some request with Deferred Date to a server. The POST request looks like:

```
{
   "text":"texst",
   "deferred_date":"2019-09-14 14:00"
}
```

I send it via Postman or the Unirest in Java and have a **201 Accepted result**.
The server stores this date value in "2019-09-14T14:00:00+03:00" format.

Since I modify my Date in Java, the final Data is stored in a String

> YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm format

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm");
String deferredTime = "";
deferredTime = dateFormat.format(oldTime);
```

My original Unirest's POST has the next body construction:

```
    .body("{\"text\":\"...\",\"deferred_date\":\"2019-09-14 06:03\"}")
```

and it works fine, but if I use my deferredTime String in my POST:

```
    .body("{\"text\":\"...\",\"deferred_date\":\"" + deferredTime + "\"}")
```

I receive a **400 Bad Request error**

```
{
   "userMessage":"Invalid input.",
   "errorCode":"invalid",
   "fields":{
      "deferred_date":[
         "Posting date Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]][+HH:MM|-HH:MM|Z]."
      ]
   },
   "internalMessage":"Invalid input."
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work if the deferredTime String variable keeps the same "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm" value as I used before.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Print the `deferredTime` and check if its format is same as the previous one

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Of course I did it and it printed correctly in needed format

Comment: The Error tells that the server expects Date in `ISO8601 format` Try this `DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");`

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya I tried it but received the same error.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You’ve got a couple of case errors in your format pattern string, you need lowercase `yyyy` and uppercase `HH`, but I can’t see how that alone would cause the bad request error.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you, it works. I used LocalDateTime and solved my problem with just several strings. Thank you!

Comment: @OleV.V. the LocalDateTime String is stored my Date in "2018-09-16T10:41:48.619" format instead of SimpleDateFormat which is stored the Date in "2018-09-16 10:41". Now, with a correct format, I receive a 201 Accepted result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with Ole V.V answer, I used the LocalDateTime String is stored my Date in "2018-09-16T10:41:48.619" format instead of SimpleDateFormat which is stored the Date in "2018-09-16 10:41". Now, with a correct format, I receive a 201 Accepted result